The code using Serveo.net behaves implicitly
The code I wrote makes a request for a TCP tunnel from Serveo.net. Serveo.net is a free service that provides temporary public tunnel creation, which is what I intend to use.
I tried to implement interrupting the tunnel process using the ENTER key, but each time I failed to find a solution, so I just ended up using a simple loop. The ENTER button, which I used with the getkey-python library, did not interrupt the tunnel process in any way - the error BlockingIoError or EOFError came out.
The code:
import subprocess

def run_tcp_tunnel():
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        ["ssh", "-R", "myalias2223:localhost:2223", "serveo.net"],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        text=True
    )

    print("Tunnel started...")

    try:
        for _ in range(2):  # The loop should only work twice
            print("The loop is still running")

            # Check if the process is completed
            if process.poll() is not None:
                print("Tunnel process finished.")
                break

            # Read the output from the SSH process
            line = process.stdout.readline()
            if line:
                print(line.strip())

    finally:
        print("Stopping the tunnel...")
        process.terminate()  # Stop the SSH process
        process.wait()  # Wait the completion the of process
        print("Tunnel stopped.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_tcp_tunnel()

I don't understand: how is this even possible, what causes such behavior? Why does the loop stop working when I press the ENTER key, even though there is no description of the program’s behavior when ENTER is pressed—how does this happen?
Here is the output:
Tunnel started...
The loop is still running
Forwarding TCP connections from serveo.net 'some address'
The loop is still running

And now when I press ENTER, the loop stops working:
Stopping the tunnel...
Tunnel stopped.

Moreover, this only works with the ENTER key, but not with any other key on the keyboard. I need the exact reasons for such behavior.
Are there any working ways to interrupt the tunnel process by pressing ENTER, but without getting the BlockingIoError or EOFError error?
Also, could you give me advice: is it acceptable to use such code that works in a non-obvious way, or should such code not be used?
